# How to open desktop application inside a web browser

Tags: java, asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, vbscript

Is it possible to open an exe application (Not launch an application) inside a web browser. I want it to be like you have embeded the application in your browser. Is that posible in VB.NET or in JAVA? I have provided the launch application. but my boss wants it to be inside the web browser, not launched by the browser. Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be a web application.

Comment: @nikpon sorry I mean open exe application.

Comment: I guess its not possible to open a an exe in your browser. Your browser can handel css, html, applets, flash etc., but no  binary file like an exe.

Comment: The browser itself an exe application. What application do you want?

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt yeah browsers can handle applets but I want it to at least open an exe inside a frame.

Comment: @nikpon example: I want command prompt inside internet explorer.

Comment: Command prompt where? Accessing the server the page was served from? Or command prompt inside the browser accessing the local machine? Either way, browsers are pretty much designed to not let this happen.

Comment: open local machines command prompt. so it is not possible?

Comment: @Bimbz The local machines are for personal use that could run a program locally but the server is for share between other local machines and internet. The server is running remotely a program called web application which gives access to the server. To get access to the server's web application used a program called web browser which is running locally. This program doesn't have a command prompt to run system programs. To run system programs you should have probably right given by the administrator.

Comment: @nikpon you didn't understand the question do you? all you have said are basic nonsense. every body knows that. all commentators got it right except you.

Comment: @Bimbz No, this is you didn't understand, the last comment almost an answer to your question which is a bunch of text without any meaning. You even didn't explain what did you ask. If you ask a question make sure you have show it to someone before the post and ask him/her if it understandable or not, or better read FAQ on this site that explain well how to write questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser naturally prevents this capability because it would be an enormous security hole.  The only way I could see you achieving this is to write some sort of browser plugin or browser extension which would allow you to achieve this but with all of the responsibilities and risks of writing this kind of code.

Comment: On Windows, it is possible to open desktop applications from the browser using [custom URL protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336242/975097).