# How to run desktop app from browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I need to launch program from browser(like battlefield when you see dialog with confirmation of starting app). Should I make an extension or there is native way to do it with javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running .exe from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser

Comment: If the external program is registered as a handler for a URI protocol, loading such a URI can cause the browser to invoke the external program after displaying a dialog.

Answer (score 5):

If the basic idea is to launch a desktop app from the web browser, the first step is to create a new Registry in Windows and path a URL Custom protocol. And if you need it you can also send parameters by changing console arguments in your app and append the parameters in your html file.

You can check here:

https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page

Answer (score -5):

check out: [Running .exe from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript/3152512#3152512)

There are cross-browser compatibility issues with executing a .EXE on a clients machine. i would suggest you look into alternative languages such as Java or even Flash. But it **can** be done in Javascript.

-normally i wouldn't answer a question like this, but i saw someone say it's not possible. **ANYTHING** is possible.