# How to access MS teams from a web application

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an angular app created and I want to add a button to it which will open up the MS teams browser or the app using the credentials i have logged in for the Angular application. ( just like a normal collaborate with teams button).

Unable to get the endpoint for doing so. Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html this might help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273424/how-to-run-desktop-app-from-browser

Comment: I want to access Microsoft Teams here

Comment: I think you can just send the user to https://teams.microsoft.com/ - is that not what you're needing?

Comment: Try redirecting user to https://teams.microsoft.com/.

Comment: You can use the `webUrl`-property of the team or channel you geht from graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSAL for log in into Microsoft, register an Application on Azure portal and then you can call graph API'S to perform your operations like getting users data.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0