# How do I launch the command prompt from the browser with javascript?

Tags: javascript, powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I want to windows command prompt and run the ping program but the ActiveXObject is not available on google chrome.
This what I want to achieve:

```
cmd.exe ping 127.0.0.1
```

Just open the prompt with that command that's what the client is asking for.

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: Can you just imagine the types of malicious code you could write if this were possible?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I imagined. But the app is for the public but a small group of admins. It's the client that wants it that way.  I think they are asking for it because back then they used to have functionalities like this with internet explorer.

Comment: Internet Explorer utilized ActiveX controls, which were compiled programs that ran inside the browser.  They were a security nightmare, which is why they aren’t around anymore.

Comment: ActiveX controls are depreciated now. If it was possible, it would allow user to do remote code execution in the server.

Comment: "But the app is for the public but a small group of admins" - doesn't matter. Just because some people wouldn't abuse such a feature does not mean said feature is a good idea. "It's the client that wants it that way" - you will have to explain to the client that this is not possible for security reasons, and this cannot be changed (thank goodness).

Answer (score 2):

That would violate all kinds of security, so that's unlikely to happen unfortunately. You'd have to get the user's permission to execute anything, so you'd need different technology.

Comment: Browsers can send commands to desktop applications using [custom URL protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336242/975097), so it is probably possible to run shell commands in this way.